# Registering an open Generic Service erroneously asks me for type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a Generic Repository which takes a Generic DbContext and a Generic Model,

The Code I have is just a basic Generic Repository like so;

```
public class DataRepo<T,M> : IDataRepo<T,M> where T:DbContext where M :class
{
    private readonly T _Context;
    private readonly M _Model;


    public DataRepo(T Context, M model)
    {
        _Context = Context;
        _Model = model;
    }
    public void Delete()
    {
       _Context.Remove(_Model);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll()
    {
        var results = await _Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

        return results;
    }

    public T GetSingleByID(int ID)
    {
        return _Context.Find<T>(ID);            
    }

    public void InsertBulkItems(ICollection<M> dataModels)
    {
        _Context.AddRange(dataModels);
    }

    public void InsertSingleItem()
    {
        _Context.Add(_Model);
    }

    public void UpdateItem()
    {
        _Context.Update(_Model);
    }
}
```

when I try to register this Service in Startup.cs, the compiler asks me for type arguments when according to [this link](https://ardalis.com/registering-open-generics-in-aspnet-core-dependency-injection) I shouldn't be getting this error?

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataRepo<>), typeof(DataRepo<>));
```

The Error I get is this;

> CS0305    Using the generic type 'IDataRepo' requires 2 type arguments

Could someone point me in the right direction with this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have multiple generic arguments, you will need to include a comma in the generic arguments

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataRepo<,>), typeof(DataRepo<,>));
```

to properly represent how many generic arguments are needed for the types involved